# Is there always a prime between $n$ and $2n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

if we are interested to seek for the numbers of primes between $1-100$ and $100-1000$ or 1000..., why we don't asked if there is a always a prime between $n$ and $2n$ mayeb this interesting question help us to predict the numbers of primes between $1-100$,or $100-1000 $ or $1000-..$?

note: $n$ is natural number $ > 1$

I would be interest for any replies or comments .Thank you

Comment: See the first result: [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=prime+between+n+and+2n)

Comment: If you want $n$ to be a natural number and the prime to be *strictly* between, I can give you a very simple counterexample.  Maybe you mean, $n \gt 1$.

Comment: let us see ur counterexample

Comment: user51189 - The counter example is n=1. There is no prime number strictly between 1 and 2. Your restriction to the naturals fails. You can easily fix this by restricting your conjecture to naturals greater 1.

Comment: ok, thank you for this , just am forget to fixed it before

Comment: Russell said it once, and I'll say it again; there's always a prime between $n$ and $2n$!!

Comment: @JpMcCarthy no need to use the double factorial there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{Chebyshev said it,}\cr
\text{And I say it again,}\cr
\text{There is always a prime}\cr
\text{Between n and 2n.}\end{array}$$

> Erdos had made his first significant contribution to number theory
>   when he was 20, and discovered an elegant proof for the theorem which
>   states that for each number greater than 1, there is always at least
>   one prime number between it and its double. The Russian mathematician
>   Chebyshev had proved this in the 19th century, but Erdos's proof was
>   far neater. News of his success was passed around Hungarian
>   mathematicians, accompanied by a rhyme: "Chebyshev said it, and I say
>   it again/There is always a prime between n and 2n."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Comment: thank you for this, i think that the same answer for this conjecture found in this book:http://www.ams.org\bookspages.acalc

Comment: Is there always a prime between n and 3n/2, for n >= 4 ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $n > 1$, then there is always at least one odd prime number $p$ satisfying $n < p < 2n$. In other words, $\pi(2n - 1) > \pi(n)$ for all $n > 1$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function. Look at [Sloane's A060715](https://oeis.org/A060715) and you'll see the only 0 is for $n = 1$.

This is called Bertrand's postulate, but Chebyshev is the one who proved it first. Ramanujan and Erdős also came up with proofs. (By the way, just in case you're wondering, this does not prove the Goldbach conjecture.)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i don't know why you wrote :one odd prime number which you wrote in the same time $p$ satisfying $n < p < 2n$ . I think all primes greater then 2 are odd .

Comment: You're correct, all primes except 2 are odd. I wanted to emphasize the inequality is strict: $n < p < 2n$ rather than $n \leq p \leq 2n$. There are no odd primes between 1 and 2, and there is only one odd prime between 2 and 4.

Comment: Oops, should've said "all primes in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ except 2 are odd." Some people around here go looking for the slightest inaccuracy to beat you up for.